# See TraceEvents when debugging Windows Driver

Tags: c++, c, driver, visual-studio-2013, wdk

I'm trying to learn how to develop drivers for Windows, and wonder how I use the TraceEvents command.

I understand that I can use TraceView on the target computer, and that it must have a pdb or ctl file. My question is how I get over these to the target computer.

When I check the settings under Configuration Properties -> Driver Install -> Deployment I can not find any settings to send these files to the target computer. Do I need to manually send over these files or is it any better method? Or can I follow the trace from my host system?

Comment: You have to manually copy files.

Comment: yes as Rohan says. To avoid manual copy, what we did is extract the .tmf file extract from .pdb (since they are much smaller), and then zip/encrypt/embed the .tmf into the module's resource section before releasing.